# Am I using RandomVaraite and ProbabilityDistribution correctly?

Tags: random

The following code does not produce an output on my Mma (version 11.3 for Windows)

```
f[x_] := ProbabilityDistribution[x^2/Integrate[y^2, {y, 0, 10}], {x, 0, 10}]
RandomVariate[f[10]]
```

It runs forever without producing any output. Am I using `RandomVariate` and `ProbabilityDistribution` correctly?

**EDIT** This is my actual function:

```
me =(*511000/29979200*)511000;
M = 11.3*10^9;
(*c=29979200;*)
z = 6;
\[Rho] = 19.32;
\[Tau][T_?NumericQ] := (12 T)/M ;
\[Beta][T_?NumericQ] := Sqrt[1 - (1/(\[Tau][T] + 1))^2];
wm[T_?NumericQ] := (2 me \[Beta][T]^2)/(1 - \[Beta][T]^2);
Zs[T_?NumericQ] = z (1 - Exp[-((125 \[Beta][T])/z^(2/3))]);
(*Numero delta prodotti da protone da 100 MeV*)

pr[en_] := 
 ProbabilityDistribution[(0.307075*79/196.96655 10^6 \[Rho] (
     10^-4(*Per micrometri*) Zs[en]^2)/(\[Beta][
        en]^2 (w)^2) (1 - (\[Beta][en]^2 (w))/
       wm[en] + (Pi \[Beta][en] Zs[en]^2)/
        137 Sqrt[(w)/wm[en]] (1 - (w)/wm[en])))/
   NIntegrate[
    0.307075*79/196.96655 10^6 \[Rho] (
     10^-4(*Per micrometri*) Zs[en]^2)/(\[Beta][
        en]^2 (w)^2) (1 - (\[Beta][en]^2 (w))/
       wm[w] + (Pi \[Beta][en] Zs[en]^2)/
        137 Sqrt[(w)/wm[en]] (1 - (w)/wm[en])), {w, 10, wm[en]}], {w, 
   10, wm[en]}]
```

Comment: Probably not: You define `f[x_]:=` as depending on `x_`, but no free `x` terms appear on the right-hand side. Examine `f[10]`'s output, I think you'll see it's not quite what you might expect. Switching `f[x_]:=` to `f=` gets plausible random variates instantly on my machine using v10.1.

Comment: @eyorble I do have a free term in `f[x_]` it is defined as `x^2/constant`

Comment: That term is absorbed by the `ProbabilityDistribution`'s choice of variable. It is not a variable of `f[x_]`, but rather a label used by `ProbabilityDistribution`. Note that `f[10]` describes a constant PDF as written, not a PDF which depends on `x`.

Comment: @eyorble and how do I define a function using `ProbabilityDistribution`? Probably I should say a parametric `ProbabilityDistribution`: I need to generate random numbers that depend on a parameter.

Comment: @mattiav27 Just plug it in the correct position. What do you want the parameter to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To define a probability distribution based on a given [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), simply define the distribution in question as follows, using an example `pdf`:

```
pdf[x_] := x^2/Integrate[y^2, {y, 0, 10}];
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[pdf[x], {x, 0, 10}];
```

You can generate random variates of this distribution using `RandomVariate`, such as:

```
RandomVariate[dist]
```

Note that the distribution is not itself a function. It contains a function and the independent parameter of that function in its specification, but the distribution itself is not actually a function.

Declaring the distribution as a function makes more sense when you are considering families of distributions. For example, consider an independent parameter `u`:

```
Clear[pdf, dist];
pdf[x_, u_] := (x+u)^2/Integrate[y^2, {y, u, 10+u}];
dist[u_] := ProbabilityDistribution[pdf[x, u], {x, 0, 10}];
```

In this case, `u` is a parameter that helps describe a family of distributions, but that each `dist[u]` is still a univariate distribution in `x`.

Comment: This is my actual distribution: `pr[en_] := 
 ProbabilityDistribution[(0.307075*79/196.96655 10^6 \[Rho] ( 10^-4 Zs[en]^2)/(\[Beta][en]^2 (w)^2) (1 - (\[Beta][en]^2 (w))/ wm[en] + (Pi \[Beta][en] Zs[en]^2)/        137 Sqrt[(w)/wm[en]] (1 - (w)/wm[en])))/
   NIntegrate[ 0.307075*79/196.96655 10^6 \[Rho] (10^-4 Zs[en]^2)/(\[Beta][       en]^2 (w)^2) (1 - (\[Beta][en]^2 (w))/ wm[w] + (Pi \[Beta][en] Zs[en]^2)/
        137 Sqrt[(w)/wm[en]] (1 - (w)/wm[en])), {w, 10, wm[en]}], {w,10, wm[en]}]` is it correct? It never produces any output.

Comment: Very hard to say without the rest of the function definitions, but I expect it's partly because `NIntegrate` is a rather expensive operation. If possible, ensuring that it is only called once per `en` value would be good.

Comment: See my edit, please

Comment: Directly evaluating `RandomVariate[pr[10]]` using the code in your edit works for me. You might want to `Clear["Global\`*"]` before that to clean up any lingering definitions that might be interfering, or restart the kernel. The code snippet you posted seems to work, aside from a warning that an assumption was violated during the evaluation.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I tried with 10.1 and 11.2. I don't have 11.3 handy, unfortunately.